# Is it possible to prevent adding BOM to output UTF-8 file? (Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8, fopen, byte-order-mark

I need some help.
I'm writing a program that opens 2 source files in UTF-8 encoding without BOM. The first contains English text and some other information, including ID. The second contains only string ID and translation. The program changes every string from the first file by replacing English chars to Russian translation from the second one and writes these strings to output file. Everything seems to be ok, but there is BOM appears in destination file. And i want to create file without BOM, like source.
I open files with fopen function in text mode with ccs=UTF-8
read string with fgetws function to wchar_t buffer
and write with fputws function to output file

Comment: Which language? Must be one from Microsoft...

Comment: @wildplasser, the C language

Comment: show the code, are we expected to debug a run time problem by guessing?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use text mode, don't use the MS `ccs=` extension to `fopen`, and don't use `fputws`. Instead use `fopen` in binary mode and write the correct UTF-8 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For a new file, there is no way to stop the the byte order mark from being created. However, you can immediately rewind after creating the file. Output will be UTF8 encoded without BOM.

```
FILE* fp = NULL;
_wfopen_s(&fp, sfn, L"wt, ccs=UTF-8");

fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET); // rewind to overwrite EF BB BF (UTF-8 BOM)
```